# SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync vs SignInManager.PasswordSignIn

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

SignInManager offers both these methods, but what is the advantage over the other? Wouldn't you always need to wait for the result of the Sign-in before proceeding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` and `SignInManager.PasswordSignIn` are doing the same thing. The difference is that the first one follows the **[TAP (Task based Asynchronous Pattern)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx)**.

> The Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP) is based on the `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` and `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>` types in the `System.Threading.Tasks` namespace, which are used to represent arbitrary asynchronous operations.

`SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` and `SignInManager.PasswordSignIn` are used to sigin a user and they need to access to your database to check if that user and the given password are correct or not. You're doing an I/O operation because your application need to connect another external ressource like disk or network (like access to a database).

It's a good practice that every I/O operation should use **TAP** that is why the presence of `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` method. You should use that method whenever you can. If you can't then use `SignInManager.PasswordSignIn`.

Because you're using ASP.Net MVC so I explain more in details in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40563046/should-all-entity-framework-methods-use-async/40564023#40564023) why you should prefer TAP.